# Android: TabActivity deprecated using Fragment instead

Tags: android, android-fragments, menubar, android-tabactivity

I'm trying to implement a MenuBar (i need it always visible so the context menu is not useful !) in the bottom of every activity for my app.
I saw that the easy to use TabActivity is now deprecated...and so i didn't get yet ho should i use the Fragments "technology".
I already found some discussion...but there is any already implemented eclipse project i could download somewhere or any easy to follow tutorial?
The one i followed over here http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/TabActivity.html was really incomplete.
I get some class cast exception due the fact i didn't get how to use FragmentActivities.
Help! :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure if you're still looking (hopefully not :) ) but here's a really good one:
[how to use fragments](http://www.vogella.com/articles/Android/article.html#fragments_tutorial)

Comment: this looks interesting...i'm still looking actually :P this is a problem i have in a lot of apps that i want to renew! :) I'll give it a look asap! Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Try running ApiDemos app shipped with SDK Samples.

http://developer.android.com/resources/samples/ApiDemos/src/com/example/android/apis/app/FragmentTabs.html

Comment: thanks for replying! i can't understand how should i use it... what should be a FragmentStack for example? i can't understand this lines:

Comment: mTabManager.addTab(mTabHost.newTabSpec("simple").setIndicator("Simple"),
                FragmentStackSupport.CountingFragment.class, null);
        mTabManager.addTab(mTabHost.newTabSpec("contacts").setIndicator("Contacts"),
                LoaderCursorSupport.CursorLoaderListFragment.class, null);
        mTabManager.addTab(mTabHost.newTabSpec("custom").setIndicator("Custom"),
                LoaderCustomSupport.AppListFragment.class, null);